# How can I invoke Gradle's repository search manually?

Tags: gradle

As a precondition for building a release version, say `acme-widgets-1.0`, I would like to search the configured repositories (or a specific repository) to make sure `acme-widgets-1.0.jar` hasn't already been published. How can I do this with Gradle? Alternatively, is there a way to configure a not-exists dependency for a specific version?

```
group = 'com.acme'
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

if (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains("release")) {
    def taskNames = gradle.startParameter.taskNames
    taskNames.add(0, "checkReleaseDoesntExist")
    gradle.startParameter.taskNames = taskNames
}

task checkReleaseDoesntExist() {
}

task release() {
    println "Building release"
}

checkReleaseDoesntExist.doLast {
    println "Checking repositories to make sure release hasn't already been built"
    // TODO What do I do here?
}
```

Comment: You can e.g. make a HTTP connection to get the artifact and if it succeeds it means it has already been published. For instance: http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/guava/guava/21.0/guava-21.0.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare a configuration with only the artifacts for which you are trying to see if they are already published.
Upon resolving this configuration, you would have an empty fileset or not.

So something along the lines of:

```
configurations {
    checkRelease { transitive = false }
}
dependency {
    checkRelease "$group:$name:$version"
}

task ('checkReleaseDoesntExist') {
    doLast {
        println "Checking repositories to make sure release hasn't already been built"
        try {
            if (!configurations.checkRelease.files.isEmpty()) {
                // already exists
            }
        }
        catch (ResolveException e) {
            // doesn't exist
        }
}
```